# PHP: session variables are overwritten by declared variables with same name

Tags: php

Just now verified that, PHP session variable is overwritten by declared variable with same name. i.e) I have session variable `$_SESSION['lan'] = 'xyz'` (global variable) and one of my PHP page x.php having variable `$lan` in `foreach` loop, at end of this loop my `$_SESSION['lan']` is overwritten by last value of the array which is used in foreach loop.

I mean `$_SESSION['lan']` having value 'abc' and that lan `$_SESSION` global variable became 'abc' hereafter.

Comment: Ensure that [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is `off`

Comment: @mAu, Yes , that is the problem, i mean register_globals should be off .

Comment: @mAu Please put that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is `off`.